# javascript timer is not working well

Tags: javascript

I`m front-end beginner.

I have a question for javascript timer.

this is my code.

```
function fn_intervalSetting(intervalTime, intervalPageMoveTime) {

    clearTimeout(reloadTimeout);
    clearTimeout(pageMoveTimeout); // <- not working

    reloadTimeout = setTimeout("fn_search()", intervalTime * defaultInterval);
    pageMoveTimeout = setTimeout("fn_pagemove()", 6000);
}
```

when I use clearTimeout(pageMoveTimeout), then fn_pagemove() not execute..
but fn_search() is working well.

I want to know what I mistake..

help me please.!

Comment: Try providing a complete [mcve].

Comment: Why callbacks are between quotes?

Comment: Did you call func fn_intervalSetting also from some interval ?

Comment: Aside: [Don't pass strings to setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Passing_string_literals).

Answer (score 0):

Try amending to the following:-

```
function fn_intervalSetting(intervalTime, intervalPageMoveTime) {

    clearTimeout(reloadTimeout);
    clearTimeout(pageMoveTimeout); // <- not working

    reloadTimeout = setTimeout(function () { fn_search() }, intervalTime * defaultInterval);
    pageMoveTimeout = setTimeout(function () { fn_pagemove() }, 6000);
}
```